# Application is not responding when trying to modify status of Gtalk using XMPPConnection in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to change the Gtalk Status using XMPPConnection in Android. But when i am trying through Wi-Fi it is unable to connect. It is giving pop-up showing Application is not responding. My Code is here:

```
                    ConnectionConfiguration conn = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com",Integer.parseInt("5222"),"gmail.com");
                m_xmppConnection = new XMPPConnection(conn);
                conn.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
                conn.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
                SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);

                try 
                {
                    m_xmppConnection.connect();
                } 
                catch (XMPPException e1) 
                {
                    displayAlertDialog(e1.getMessage());
                }

                try
                {
                    Log.d("Testing", "try to connect using XMPPConnection");

                    Log.d("Testing", "try to connect using XMPPConnection-----");
                    if(m_xmppConnection.isConnected())
                    {
                        Log.d("Testing", "It is connected with XMPPConnection");
                        m_xmppConnection.login(strUname, strPwd);
                    }
                    Log.d("Testing", "after giving user name and pwd-----");
                    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                    m_strGtPrevMsg = presence.getStatus();
                    m_spEditor.putString("prevmsg", m_strGtPrevMsg);
                    m_spEditor.commit();
                    presence.setStatus(strStatus);
                    Log.d("Testing", "status saved");
                    presence.setPriority(24);
                    presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);

                    m_xmppConnection.sendPacket(presence);
                    Log.d("Testing", "packet send");
                }

                catch(XMPPException e)
                {
//                  e.printStackTrace();

                    displayAlertDialog(e.getMessage());
                }
```

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: You do the connection on the UI thread, right?

Make an AsnycTask and do your connection and status changes there.

Comment: The exception it is showing in DDMS: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: Which has nothing to do with my answer, nor my guess. Could you clarify in which context you execute the code you have posted?

Comment: Actually my app will start when a particular time will reach(Like 10 PM). This is i am doing by use of service. So when the service will start, it will try to change the Gtalk status.

Comment: When i am trying to connect with network using SIM, it is connecting. But when i am trying with Wi-Fi, it is not working.

Comment: So if you do it in `onStart()`, it runs on the UI Thread. You should never do anything that can take a long time on the UI Thread. To change the status, just move your code into an AsyncTask or Thread and start it in the `onStart()` method. That will prevent the ANR message...

Comment: So how can i make it using AsyncTask??

Comment: The basics can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: Yes, using AsynTask, i did it.Now ANR message is not coming. but it is throwing illegalStateException saying Not Connected to server.

Comment: as this is another topic, you should start a new question and post the code of you AyncTask there.